# Android: Getting list row # from child button press

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity

I have a listview of store building locations.  Each row contains address, phone, hours, etc.  I added a button so that when pressed the dialer intent can be called.

My method is called when a button is pressed, but I can't figure out how to get the row #, which I need.

Here's what I have.  How do I get the listview row # that this button child is in?

```
public void myPhoneClickHandler(View v) 
{
    int key_RowId =0;
    Toast displayToast = Toast.makeText(branchPicker.this,
            "You pressed:" + key_RowId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    displayToast.show();
}
```

---

```
<Button 
android:text="Call" 
android:id="@+id/bBranchCall"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="myPhoneClickHandler">
```

Thanks Gopal, it worked

Solution:

```
public void myPhoneClickHandler(View v) 
{
    ListView lv = getListView();

    if (lv == null)
        return;

    final int position = lv.getPositionForView(v);
    if (position < 0)
        return;

    Toast displayToast = Toast.makeText(branchPicker.this,
            "You pressed:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    displayToast.show();
}
```

Comment: First thing You have to call setTag on Button View before you call getTag, thats why you are getting NullPointerException. I assume "myPhonceClickHandler" call you might have mentioned in xml file, correct me if I am wrong. What adapter are you using to populate your list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call setTag on Button and in onClick call getTag on the Button View. [Link about Set Tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29)

Used setTag and getTag in one of my project here is [Link](https://github.com/gopalB/FeedReader/blob/master/src/com/feedReader/detail/FeedDetailAdapter.java). Search for onClick method, Hope this helps in resolving your issue.

Comment: hrmmm.     public void myPhoneClickHandler(View v)  {final int key_RowId =(Integer) v.getTag();} is crashing.  I put a break on the line and it's on the getTag()

Comment: Can you please copy stacktrace from logcat, so it will be easy to find whats going wrong. And can you let me know, what are you passing in setTag function.

Comment: One more clarification I need from you, do every row of ListView has button ?

Comment: Yes.  Every row has 2 buttons.  1 for phone, and another for navigation.

Comment: If you have button in each row of ListView OnItemClick event won't fire because of button. Assuming your android:id="@+id/bBranchCall" is id for button through which you want to make call. So, when you click on it myPhoneClickHandler will get called, inside that method you are getting reference of Button View. Then call v.getParent() type cast it with proper layout. And then on Layout reference call findViewById(R.id.branchPhone) which will give you reference for your TextView of particular row where you might have mentioned phone number. Hope this help.

Comment: Try calling getPositionForView in myProgramClickHandler. Here is [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getPositionForView(android.view.View))

Answer (score 0):

well, i guess you can do lvItems.getSelectedItem(), but why don't you use an onItemClickListener and attach that to the listview?

Comment: use onItemClickListener on the listview or the buttons?  For each row in the list(store location), I want a way to dial, and call navigation.